# Detecting that a ThreadPool WorkItem has completed/waiting for completion

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, threadpool

For whatever reason, `ThreadPool`'s `QueueWorkItem` doesn't return an `IAsyncResult` or some other handle to the work item, which would allow to wait until it's completed. There are `RegisterWait...` methods, but you have to pass a `WaitHandle` and creating them is expensive (see `IAsyncResult` documentation, which advises you to delay creating a `WaitHandle` until requested). The Task Parallel Library will fix this lack, but there is a long wait before that's available. So, are there any problems with this design:

```
public class Concurrent<T> {
    private ManualResetEvent _resetEvent;
    private T _result;

    public Concurrent(Func<T> f) {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => {
                                         _result = f();
                                         if (_resetEvent != null)
                                             _resetEvent.Set();
                                     });
    }

    public WaitHandle WaitHandle {
        get {
            if (_resetEvent == null)
                _resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(_result != null);
            return _resetEvent;
        }

    ...
```

EDIT:
I asked a [follow-up question about the concerns which arise when using async delegates instead of the ThreadPool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406915/using-begininvoke-endinvoke-in-a-multithreaded-fashion-how-do-asynccallback-asy).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you've got a race condition between fetching the WaitHandle and setting it. Do you really want the caller to be waiting forever if they happen to be a tiny bit late?

You should probably do some appropriate locking and keep an "I've finished" flag so that if you *do* create the WaitHandle after it's finished, you set it before returning it.

I'd also personally write a static factory method rather than just using a public constructor - or make it a "create and *then* explicitly start" pattern. Queuing the work item in the constructor feels weird to me.

Comment: Note that I pass `_result != null` as the parameter to the ManualResetEvent constructor. (This won't work for structs, but the idea is the same.) `_result != null` serves as the finishing flag here (not in the actual implementation, of course). Yes, judicious locking is needed here. (continued...)

Comment: A static factory method goes without saying, I very rarely write a generic public constructor without a corresponding static method.

Comment: I wouldn't make the constructor public in the first place though. You should also consider methods which return null...

Comment: As I said, `_result != null` won't be used in the actual implementation (this would also work badly if the method throws an exception).

Answer (score 3):

Why aren't you using an asynchronous delegate, as demostrated here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h80ttd5f.aspx

That would make Concurrent obsolete, no?

Comment: 1) Concurrent provides a more easily usable API (I think); 2) Concurrent is just one subtype of Future<T>, there are others which work differently (lazy values, promises); 3) (Most important) Because I didn't notice that Concurrent could be implemented as just a facade over asynchronous delegates.

Comment: Ah, I thought from the start this had something to do with futures :-).